# Launching second activity with category home from the first activity

Tags: android

I want to make android launcher. Can someone say how can I have 2 activities and the first one should start the second one which is have to have `category:home` in its `intent-filter`. I've tried this but it stops when I press button and in log I have `Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.amadey.myapplication3/com.example.amadey.myapplication3.HomeScreen}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeScreen.class));
            }
        });
    }

}
```

HomeScreen.class:

```
    public class HomeScreen extends Activity {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        }

     }
```

My manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.amadey.myapplication3" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

                <intent-filter>

                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

                </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.amadey.myapplication3.HomeScreen">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You will have to be more specific than that

Comment: @DavidMedenjak , What do you mean?

Comment: What do you intend to do? What is your code? What is your problem? What have you tried so far to solve it? You question is very hard to understand as it is currently written

Comment: First, make sure the full class name of HomeScreen matches the string you used in the `android:name` property of the activity declaration in the manifest.

Comment: @DougStevenson They are matche.I press Ctrl+left mouse button and I saw my HomeScreen class

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I've edited it.Please take a look